# Fade transistion without fading to blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found some code which fades out the body, then fades in the body of the next page, but this is a bit ugly and increases loading time.

Is it possible to fade directly to the other page, as in, fade out of the old, and fade in with the new at the same time?

**JS:** (Reviewers, please check the code before you make edits next time.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').css('display', 'none');
$('body').fadeIn(500);

$('a').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = this.href;
    $('body').fadeOut(100, newpage);

});

function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
}

});
```

Comment: I'd look at using a [template engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/). Can make moving between pages/content alot easier and improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible with normal navigation. To do that you need the content from both pages in the same page at the same time. This changes how you handle pages completely, as you need to load the body content for your different pages using AJAX into elements in a single page instead of navigating to the new page.

Comment: Ah I see. So I will have to have each separate page as a DIV and fade between them.

Comment: Actually I have nearly achieved this by only fading out the content.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, nearly is halfways, but you can't fade in the new content at the same time if it's not there.